# Поле Друзей Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, веб-программирование, laravel

Пишу сайт на laravel. Есть таблица (модель) `user` и в нем поле `friends` т.е. поле друзей пользователя. Я никогда не реализовывал сайты с системой друзей и не знаю как хранить друзей пользователей. Пока только идея сохранять большой `json` массив с `id` друзей. Как бы вы это сделали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Худшая идея этот массив.

А если друзей будет миллион, и длинна массива превысит длинну поля?

Для этого нужно сделать отдельную таблицу с полями:

```
id - PK,
user_id - ид пользователя
friend_id - ид друга
```